# What should I do when the answer of my question is in a commentary?

Tags: support, answers

I have the right answer to my question in a commentary. How do I accept an answer in this situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ask the commentator to post it as an answer or take it and self-answer your question.

Comment: If doing the latter you might want to wait for the commenter to have a chance to earn his rep by posting an answer, and if they don't, mark the answer as CW.

Comment: Thanks @Dominic Rodger. But what's "CW"?

Comment: @TomHarris "Community Wiki": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts